# My numpy select and where statement is leaving null values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I've tried to use both numpy `select` and `where` statements to develop another column in my dataframe.  Neither is working and I'm not sure why.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

condition = [df_l['Policy Form'] == 'HO3',
             df_l['Policy Form'] == 'HO3C']
replace = [100000, 100000]
df_l['Personal Liability limit (08)'] = np.select(condition, replace, default = 50000)
```

I also tried:

```
df_l['Personal Liability limit (08)'] = np.where((df_l['Policy Form'] == 'HO3') | df_l['Policy Form'] == 'HO3C', 100000, 50000)
```

I'm not sure why either is working though.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without NumPy, directly in Pandas:

```
df_l['Personal Liability limit (08)'] = 50000
selection = (df_l['Policy Form'] == 'HO3') | (df_l['Policy Form'] == 'HO3C')
df_l.loc[selection, 'Personal Liability limit (08)'] = 100000
```